# In XCUITests, how to wait for existence of several ui elements?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest

What is the best way to wait for existence of multiple `XCUIElement`s while doing UITests in XCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code to be working. We run a loop for a timeout duration, waiting 1 second between the iterations. On every step we check if all the elements exist, return true if they do, continue otherwise.

```
func waitForExistenceOfAll(elements: [XCUIElement], for timeout: TimeInterval) -> Bool {
        guard elements.count > 0 else {
            return true
        }
        let startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        while (NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime <= timeout) {
            var allExist = true
            for element in elements {
                if !element.exists {
                    allExist = false
                    break
                }
            }
            if allExist {
                return true
            }
            sleep(1)
        }
        return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more concise version:

```swift
func waitForExistenceOfAll(elements: [XCUIElement], for timeout: TimeInterval) -> Bool {
    for _ in 0 ... Int(timeout) {
        if elements.filter({ $0.exists == false }).isEmpty {
            return true
        }

        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using variadic functions:

```
public func exists(_ elements: XCUIElement..., timeout: TimeInterval = 5.0) -> Bool {
    for element in elements {
        if !element.waitForExistence(timeout: timeout) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

usage:

```
exists(el1, el2, el3)
```